# Xcode 5 wrong font size on UITextField after editing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have UITextFields with custom font and size. Everything worked fine till I changed to Xcode 5 to fix all the changes with new iOS/Xcode. Now when I check my UITextFields they have the right font on placeholder and while editing, but when I stop editing the font size gets bigger. So why now with Xcode 5 it doesn't work?

Screenshots: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u73w11uk3duu3y1/XWssa98Rfj)

Code to set font hasn't changed:

```
[_eventName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT_FUTURASTD_LIGHT size:16]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had an issue when inserting rows in a table - the text field in the table cell would use the UILabel proxy font, not the font set on its font property.  Scrolling off the screen and back on would then show the correct font.

The only way I was able to fix this was to override UITextField, add a custom drawRect - in here I had to set self.font to nil, then reset self.font to the value I desired.

Chris

Comment: I have solved this similarly, by creating my own class extending UITextView which is made editable. But this is only constructive answer so I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made changes to the appearance proxy for UILabels? I'm having a similar issue where it appears as if UITextField's text is rendered as a UILabel after editing is completed. Overriding my appearance proxy settings on UILabel fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this answer, but here I go. That project was started by other developer and I didnt get any documentation, so Im not sure, but I dont think that proxy has been modified. The way I solved this was by replacing all UITextFields with custom UITextViews where I added necessary functionality from UITextFields.

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to use sizeWithAttributes: instead, which now takes an NSDictionary. Pass in the pair with key UITextAttributeFont and your font object like this :

```
[_eventName.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT_FUTURASTD_LIGHT size:16]}]
```

Comment: What is that "string"? Not sure how to use it. Also does this work only on iOS7?

Comment: Tried using it like this [_eventName.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:APP_FONT_FUTURASTD_LIGHT size:16]}]; but that doesn't work, so probably wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and just like described by chrisoneiota the problem is that the UITextField uses a UILabel for some situations.  I solved it also by overriding the UITextField, but instead of implementing `drawInRect:` I do:

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
        label.font = self.font;
    }
    [super addSubview:view];
}
```

This appears to work well.